Can information exist without a carrier?
Does creation of information yield any results when there is nothing to "store" it?
To put it in an example: if a tree branch falls in the forest and nobody sees or hears it, did it actually fall?
The information cannot be "stored" with our sight or hearing, so until we go to said forest and compare the situation from before and after the act of falling, we cannot really tell if the branch did in fact fall.

Why can't the information be stored in the very branch that fell and is now on the ground? Also the whole idea that events don't actually happen unless someone knows about it is strange. When planet Earth formed nobody was there to watch it, yet obviously it happened. Or if food in a tin can is rotten, nobody will know about it until someone opens the can. It seems more parcimonious to think the food slowly rot inside the can while it was stored rather than it instantly became rottent the moment the can was opened.

Your question is assuming a point of view that information somehow doesn't exist outside of human perception, in possibly a solipsist way. It also hinges on what "information" is and what it means for it to be "carried" or "stored" by/in something.

Seems like an interesting physics question rather than a philosophy question.

Where do you draw the line between "information" and "action" and what do you consider storing? Like there's ton of things with which the branch has interacted in the act of falling so yeah the environment will "store" the information in itself. So would you mind defining these terms more thoroughly?

There were many other witnesses to the tree falling - foxes, bees, etc. Why do think the tree needs your permission to be in the fallen state? Or do you also think all the other creatures are only 'painted in' on your arrival too?

The information that the branch fell is present in the light cone of that event. Whether any human being interacts with that light cone is another matter. Information is not the exclusive property of human beings.

Well, the approach is possibly solipsistic, because I was thinking about it from my (or every other individual's) perception, but you cannot also assume that there are any witnesses to the tree falling. The information can be stored inside of the branch, inside of the tree, but then, it IS stored somewhere, whereas my question was if this  information about the falling branch could exist without being "stored" anywhere - not in the branch, not being witnessed by bees, not seen or heard by anyone and anything.
The existence of information outside of human body does not imply being carried.

The idea that if you didn't see the tree fall, then it didn't fall, means that no leaves grow, not flowers open, no clouds form, no rain falls until you become involved, and that by extension, nothing outside your field of view exists until you turn round to look, when the Great Construction Team rapidly puts it all together, just for you. If you're quick, you can sometimes make out a bit of 4x2 being whipped out of sight.

@bumble I vote that bumble type his comment as an answer and the OP mark it as resolved: "The information that the branch fell is present in the light cone of that event." That's all there is to it. Case closed.

I think this topic would be improved by a definition of what you mean by "information" or a clarification of what philosophical tradition you're interested in answers from? As it stands, I think the only answer is "it depends on how you define information, carrier, exist, and can", or else other people trying to do their own philosophizing on what the 'proper' definition of those is, which is not useful.

Imagine that a photon and anti-photon spring in to existence as a pair of virtual particles, then annihilate again, leaving nothing behind and interacting with no other particles. The information is: it happened. Where is this information now? Nowhere. Information can be lost or 'destroyed', ask anyone whose computer failed.
